# form id renamed to aspnetForm

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When I compile and run a web application ASP.NET appears to be renaming the id of the form on the page, from id="login" to id="aspnetForm". It's messing up my stylesheet which expects the form with login for the id. Changing the css is not an option as it was provided by a designer and I don't want to modify it at all. How do I stop aspnet doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following question detailing controlling client ids in asp.net

[ASP.Net 3.5: Specifying a control's HTML ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132829/asp-net-3-5-specifying-a-controls-html-id)